# Trying to add validators in Jira workflow for universal validator?

Tags: jira

I am trying to check for the custom field "Create sub-tasks" which is a radio button and has the following value - None, Yes, No. I want to add a validator to check if the value is either Yes or No. However, when I have placed the validator, it shows me some errors.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Krishna, welcome to PM.SE! What are you trying to achieve to implement this? This question might be more important than the current question.

Comment: Changing the question copy could be better.